# Visual Studio 2013 slow while executing a MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I know that this is an off-topic question, but I hope some people can share their experience.

When I run (ctrl+F5) my MVC 5 project, the entire Visual Studio get slow.

To go back to normal, I need to close the browser.

Is that the same for everybody?

#### Update

Btw, my computer is a i5 with 8GB memory (dell 7020).

---

## Solution I found:

If we disable "Browser Link" in Visual Studio will work perfect:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat, but I wouldn't say it's a universal problem. There's a lot of infrastructure to making debugging in Visual Studio work, and loading all that up *could* cause Visual Studio or your computer in general to slow down. However, it that occurs to an unacceptable point, then the situation is probably simply that your computer does not have the proper amount of resources to be running Visual Studio in the first place. The system requirements for even the Ultimate version of VS2013 are really pretty minimal, but if you don't meet these, you should especially consider upgrading your machine:

> - 1.6 GHz or faster processor
> - 1 GB of RAM (1.5 GB if running on a virtual machine)
> - 20 GB of available hard disk space
> - 5400 RPM hard disk drive
> - DirectX 9-capable video card that runs at 1024 x 768 or higher display resolution

([source](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-ultimate-with-msdn-vs#Fragment_SystemRequirements))

However, bear in mind that system requirements are always low-ball estimates. It means the program will "run", but it doesn't guarantee optimal performance, and almost assuredly does not take into account anything else running on the machine. Also, these are in addition to your OS requirements. For example, Windows 8.1 requires 2GB of RAM for a 64-bit install. That means if you want to run Visual Studio 2013 on top of that, you'll need at least a total of 3-4GB. If you're running any other software, you'll need to take those resources into account as well.

Long and short, yes, debugging in Visual Studio will be slower than not debugging. However, it should very much still be usable while debugging. If it's so slow that it's actually inhibiting you, then you're most likely resource constrained. Consider closing any other big applications that might be running (Photoshop, for example) or simply adding more RAM to the machine. Switching out your drive with and SSD, if it's not already an SSD will help dramatically as well, especially if you're RAM-constrained.

Comment: Hi Chris, but I´m not debugging. Only running app.

Comment: Well, it should be a little less resource-intensive, then, but IIS Express isn't exactly efficient, so you could still experience some slow down. Regardless, the same advice applies, perhaps even more so given that you're not even debugging. Make sure you have a good amount of resources on your computer. Check the task manager and make sure you're well below 50% in any one resource utilization metric there. If you're at 80-90% of RAM for example, that means you're paging, and if you have a slow drive, your computer will slow down dramatically as a result.

Comment: I'm running VS2013 on an i7 Haswell Dual Core with Hyper-threading, running at 1.70GHz with 8GB RAM. Notably, I also have an SSD drive housing both the OS and all applications. With those specs, I can run even multiple instances of VS2013 along-side Photoshop, SQL Server, and Chrome with 20+ tabs (I'm a tab horder). Everything runs buttery smooth. The i7 vs your i5 probably makes a little difference, but otherwise the our specs seem pretty similar. Do you have an SSD or is it a traditional mechanical drive?

Comment: Its a traditional one. I will try in a ssd.

Comment: Well, I can't say definitively because frankly I haven't used anything but an SSD for my system drives for more than 5 years now, but 8GB of RAM + SSD is *vastly* different than 8GB of RAM with something like a 5400 RPM  mechanical drive. SSD is still nowhere near as fast as RAM, but it's astronomically faster than a mechanical drive. So when you start to page, with an SSD, it's barely noticeable. That means you can theoretically get by with less RAM on the machine because paging is so quick.